# Exception: java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Tags: java

I am getting an exception `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`:
I am posting my full code.
This is the code of encoding a wav file.
ArrayStoreException

```
 package org.xiph.speex;

import static java.nio.file.Files.size;

/**
 * Main Speex Encoder class.
 * This class encodes the given PCM 16bit samples into Speex packets.
 *
 * @author Marc Gimpel, Wimba S.A. (mgimpel@horizonwimba.com)
 * @version $Revision: 1.6 $
 */
public class SpeexEncoder
{
  /**
   * Version of the Speex Encoder
   */
  public static final String VERSION = "Java Speex Encoder v0.9.7 ($Revision: 1.6 $)";

  private Encoder encoder;
 private Bits    bits;
  private float[] rawData;
  private int     sampleRate;
  private int     channels;
  private int     frameSize;

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  public SpeexEncoder()
  {
    bits = new Bits();
  }

  /**
   * initialization
   * @param mode       the mode of the encoder (0=NB, 1=WB, 2=UWB).
   * @param quality    the quality setting of the encoder (between 0 and 10).
   * @param sampleRate the number of samples per second.
   * @param channels   the number of audio channels (1=mono, 2=stereo, ...).
   * @return true if initialisation successful.
   */
  public boolean init(final int mode,
                      final int quality,
                      final int sampleRate,
                      final int channels)
  {
    switch (mode) {
      case 0:
        encoder = new NbEncoder();
        ((NbEncoder)encoder).nbinit();
        break;
//Wideband
      case 1:
        encoder = new SbEncoder();
        ((SbEncoder)encoder).wbinit();
        break;
      case 2:
        encoder = new SbEncoder();
        ((SbEncoder)encoder).uwbinit();
        break;
//*/
      default:
        return false;
    }

    /* initialize the speex decoder */
    encoder.setQuality(quality);

    /* set decoder format and properties */
    this.frameSize  = encoder.getFrameSize();
    this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
    this.channels   = channels;
    rawData         = new float[channels*frameSize];

    bits.init();
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the Encoder being used (Narrowband, Wideband or Ultrawideband).
   * @return the Encoder being used (Narrowband, Wideband or Ultrawideband).
   */
  public Encoder getEncoder()
  {
    return encoder;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the sample rate.
   * @return the sample rate.
   */
  public int getSampleRate()
  {
    return sampleRate;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of channels.
   * @return the number of channels.
   */
  public int getChannels()
  {
    return channels;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the size of a frame.
   * @return the size of a frame.
   */
  public int getFrameSize()
  {
    return frameSize;
  }

    public void setComplexity(int complexity) {
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

  /**
   * Pull the decoded data out into a byte array at the given offset
   * and returns the number of bytes of encoded data just read.

   * @param offset
   * @return the number of bytes of encoded data just read.
   */
  public int getProcessedData(final byte[] data, final int offset)
  {
      int size = bits.getBufferSize();
   System.out.println("value is:"+bits.getBuffer());
   System.arraycopy(bits.getBuffer(),0, data, offset,size);
   bits.init();
 // System.out.println("size is:"+ size);
   return size;
  }
 /**
   * Returns the number of bytes of encoded data ready to be read.
   * @return the number of bytes of encoded data ready to be read.
   */
  public void getProcessedDataByteSize()
  {
  }

  /**
   * This is where the actual encoding takes place
   * @param data
   * @param offset
   * @param len
   * @return true if successful.
   */
  public boolean processData(final byte[] data,
                             final int offset,
                             final int len)
  {
    // converty raw bytes into float samples
   mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float(data, offset, rawData, 0, len/2);
    // encode the bitstream
    return processData(rawData, len/2);
  }

  /**
   * Encode an array of shorts.
   * @param data
   * @param offset
   * @param numShorts
   * @return true if successful.
   */
  public boolean processData(final short[] data,
                             final int offset,
                             final int numShorts)
  {
    int numSamplesRequired = channels * frameSize;
    if (numShorts != numSamplesRequired) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("SpeexEncoder requires " + numSamplesRequired + " samples to process a Frame, not " + numShorts);
    }
    // convert shorts into float samples,
    for (int i=0; i<numShorts; i++) {
      rawData[i] = data[offset + i ];
    }
    // encode the bitstream
    return processData(rawData, numShorts);
  }

  /**
   * Encode an array of floats.
   * @param data
   * @param numSamples
   * @return true if successful.
   */
  public boolean processData(final float[] data, final int numSamples)
  {
    int numSamplesRequired = channels * frameSize;
    if (numSamples != numSamplesRequired) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("SpeexEncoder requires " + numSamplesRequired + " samples to process a Frame, not " + numSamples );
    }
    // encode the bitstream
    if (channels==2) {
      Stereo.encode(bits, data, frameSize);
    }
    encoder.encode(bits, data);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Converts a 16 bit linear PCM stream (in the form of a byte array)
   * into a floating point PCM stream (in the form of an float array).
   * Here are some important details about the encoding:
   * <ul>
   * <li> Java uses big endian for shorts and ints, and Windows uses little Endian.
   *      Therefore, shorts and ints must be read as sequences of bytes and
   *      combined with shifting operations.
   * </ul>
   * @param pcm16bitBytes - byte array of linear 16-bit PCM formated audio.
   * @param offsetInput
   * @param samples - float array to receive the 16-bit linear audio samples.
   * @param offsetOutput
   * @param length
   */
  public static void mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float(final byte[] pcm16bitBytes,
                                                   final int offsetInput,
                                                   final float[] samples,
                                                   final int offsetOutput,
                                                   final int length)
  {
    if (pcm16bitBytes.length - offsetInput < 2 * length) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient Samples to convert to floats");
    }
    if (samples.length - offsetOutput < length) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient float buffer to convert the samples");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      samples[offsetOutput+i] = ((pcm16bitBytes[offsetInput+2*i] & 0xff) | (pcm16bitBytes[offsetInput+2*i+1] << 8)); // no & 0xff at the end to keep the sign
    }
  }

   // public int getProcessedData(byte[] temp, int i) {
      //  return 0;
  //      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
  //  }






    private static class Stereo {

        private static void encode(Bits bits, float[] data, int frameSize) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        private Stereo() {
        }
    }


     static class Bits {
      //  private Object getBuffer;
       // private Object getBufferSize;


       // private void Bits() {
     //   }

        private int getBufferSize() {
           // System.out.println("hello");
           return 0;
       //  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        public int getBuffer() {
           // return null;
          return 0;
        //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }



       public int init() {
           return 0;
      //      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

       }
     }
}
```

Please help me to get out of this.
This is my  full code.
 getting an exception ArrayStoreException in getProcessedData

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: What's the return type of `bits.getBuffer()`? Does it return an array that is big enough to hold the array `data`?

Comment: "An ArrayStoreException is thrown and the destination is not modified:

The src argument refers to an object that is not an array.
The dest argument refers to an object that is not an array.
The src argument and dest argument refer to arrays whose component types are different primitive types.
The src argument refers to an array with a primitive component type and the dest argument refers to an array with a reference component type.
The src argument refers to an array with a reference component type and the dest argument refers to an array with a primitive component type."

Comment: @ 1337 please explain me in the context of my code.

Comment: @Anika What is `bits`  ?

Comment: @ bjlee72 the return type of bits.getBuffer() is int. It does not return an array that is big enough to hold the array data

Comment: @ sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ bits is the variable of class Bits. I have posted my full code. please help me what should i do

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the rest of the code you provided, Google found a copy of the code from

https://github.com/phono/PhonoSDK/blob/master/modules/phono-java-audio/src/java/org/xiph/speex/

Where you can see an implementation for [Bits](https://github.com/phono/PhonoSDK/blob/master/modules/phono-java-audio/src/java/org/xiph/speex/Bits.java) and [Stereo](https://github.com/phono/PhonoSDK/blob/master/modules/phono-java-audio/src/java/org/xiph/speex/Stereo.java)

In fact a simpler solution is to do

```
git clone https://github.com/phono/PhonoSDK
```

and you will have a copy of all the code you might need.

> the return type of bits.getBuffer() is int.

The method `arraycopy` only works on arrays, as the name suggests.  You have to copy from one array, to another of the same type.  You can't copy from say `int[]` to `byte[]` and you can't copy from an `int` to a `byte[]`.

BTW If you have a `getBufferSize()` you might expect `getBuffer()` to return a buffer like a `byte[]` of the size `getBufferSize()`  There appears to be something broken about your API.

Comment: I have posted my full code. please help me what should i do

Comment: @Anika I think you should work out what `Bits` is for, and how you intend to implement it.

Comment: @Anika I am assuming you didn't write the rest of the code, why don't you get `Bits` from the same place you got the code?  Perhaps you could ask the author for a copy from his/her email address?

Comment: @Anika since you copied the first class, I suggest you google and copy the other classes as well. I have added links to the come in my answer.

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey I have added the code for class Bits but still the same exception persists...

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey I have added the code for Bits(),getbuffer(),getbufferSize(). The value is printed infinitely.. What to do

Comment: @Anika why don't you just copy the working code for `Bits` and `Stereo` like you did for the other code?  I have provided the links in my answer.

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey I have added the working code for bits which u provide in ur link but code for stereo gav=e lot of errors .What to do??

Comment: @Anika This package comes with many classes, what happens when you checkout the whole module and try to build it. It should compile without error.

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey The code is running but printing the value infinitely and not stopping.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the data type of the arrays.

```
System.arraycopy(bits.getBuffer(),0, data, offset,size);
```

in this line control **bits.getBuffer()**-type and **data**-type

you passed the primitive data type for first parameter, it must be Object. you say `System.arraycopy(bits.getBuffer(),0, data, offset,size); bits.getBuffer()` is primitive not a Object.

Comment: ... are the same type.

Comment: I have posted my full code. please help me what should i do.

Comment: well... use the this code for the problem line Arrays.copyOf(original, newLength); it returns the array and assign to the array.

you can use Arrays.copyOfRange

Comment: @  Peter Lawrey I have posted my full code. please help me what should i do.

Comment: @Semih Okan Pehlivan I didn't get ur statement . use the this code for the problem line –

Comment: @Anika Do ypou want to copy array to target array? You can use the Arrays.copyOf() method and also System.arraycopy has five parameter (Object,int,Object,int,int). you passed the primitive data type for first parameter, it must be Object. you say `System.arraycopy(bits.getBuffer(),0, data, offset,size);`
`bits.getBuffer()` is primitive not a Object. Ok ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if I were you, I will modify the code as follows. As the codes are full of many placeholders, plz replace them with your logics.

```
package org.xiph.speex;


class Bits {
    byte[] backingArray;

    Bits() {
        this.backingArray = new byte[65535];
    }

    Bits(int size) {
        this.backingArray = new byte[size];
    }

    int getBufferSize() {
        return this.backingArray.length;
    }

    public byte[] getBuffer() {
        return this.backingArray;
    }

    public int feed(byte[] src, int offset, int sz) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if ( sz > this.backingArray.length ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("data is too big to fit in");
        }

        if ( src.length - offset < sz ) {
            sz = src.length - offset;
        }

        System.arraycopy(src, offset, this.backingArray, 0, sz);
        return sz;
    }

    public void init() {
        // whatever
    }
}

class Stereo {

    static void encode(Bits bits, float[] data, int frameSize) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    Stereo() {
    }
}

interface Encoder {
    void init();
    void setQuality(int quality);
    int getFrameSize();
    void encode(Bits bits, float[] data);
}

class NarrowBandEncoder implements Encoder {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        // whatever
    }

    @Override
    public void setQuality(int quality) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public int getFrameSize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(Bits bits, float[] data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

class WidebandEncoder implements Encoder {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        // whatever
    }

    @Override
    public void setQuality(int quality) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public int getFrameSize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(Bits bits, float[] data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

class UltraWidebandEncoder implements Encoder {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        // whatever
    }

    @Override
    public void setQuality(int quality) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public int getFrameSize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(Bits bits, float[] data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

enum EncodingMode {
    NARROW_BAND(NarrowBandEncoder::new),
    WIDE_BAND(WidebandEncoder::new),
    ULTRA_WIDE_BAND(UltraWidebandEncoder::new);

    private Supplier<? extends Encoder> encoder;

    private EncodingMode(Supplier<? extends Encoder> supplier) {
        this.encoder = supplier;
    }

    public Encoder createEncoder() {
        return this.encoder.get();
    }
}


/**
 * Main Speex Encoder class.
 * This class encodes the given PCM 16bit samples into Speex packets.
 *
 * @author Marc Gimpel, Wimba S.A. (mgimpel@horizonwimba.com)
 * @version $Revision: 1.6 $
 */
public class SpeexEncoder
{
    /**
     * Version of the Speex Encoder
     */
    public static final String VERSION = "Java Speex Encoder v0.9.7 ($Revision: 1.6 $)";

    private Encoder encoder;
    private Bits    bits;
    private float[] rawData;
    private int     sampleRate;
    private int     channels;
    private int     frameSize;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public SpeexEncoder()
    {
        bits = new Bits();
    }

    /**
     * initialization
     * @param mode       the mode of the encoder (0=NB, 1=WB, 2=UWB).
     * @param quality    the quality setting of the encoder (between 0 and 10).
     * @param sampleRate the number of samples per second.
     * @param channels   the number of audio channels (1=mono, 2=stereo, ...).
     * @return true if initialisation successful.
     */
    public boolean init(final EncodingMode mode,
            final int quality,
            final int sampleRate,
            final int channels)
    {
        this.encoder = mode.createEncoder();
        this.encoder.init();

        /* initialize the speex decoder */
        this.encoder.setQuality(quality);

        /* set decoder format and properties */
        this.frameSize  = encoder.getFrameSize();
        this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
        this.channels   = channels;
        this.rawData    = new float[channels*frameSize];

        this.bits.init();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Encoder being used (Narrowband, Wideband or Ultrawideband).
     * @return the Encoder being used (Narrowband, Wideband or Ultrawideband).
     */
    public Encoder getEncoder()
    {
        return encoder;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the sample rate.
     * @return the sample rate.
     */
    public int getSampleRate()
    {
        return sampleRate;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of channels.
     * @return the number of channels.
     */
    public int getChannels()
    {
        return channels;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the size of a frame.
     * @return the size of a frame.
     */
    public int getFrameSize()
    {
        return frameSize;
    }

    public void setComplexity(int complexity) {
        //        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    /**
     * Pull the decoded data out into a byte array at the given offset
     * and returns the number of bytes of encoded data just read.

     * @param offset
     * @return the number of bytes of encoded data just read.
     */
    public int getProcessedData(final byte[] data, final int offset)
    {
        int sz = this.bits.feed(data, offset, this.bits.getBufferSize());
        this.bits.init();
        return sz;
    }
    /**
     * Returns the number of bytes of encoded data ready to be read.
     * @return the number of bytes of encoded data ready to be read.
     */
    public void getProcessedDataByteSize()
    {
        // ?
    }

    /**
     * This is where the actual encoding takes place
     * @param data
     * @param offset
     * @param len
     * @return true if successful.
     */
    public boolean processData(final byte[] data,
            final int offset,
            final int len)
    {
        // converty raw bytes into float samples
        mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float(data, offset, rawData, 0, len/2);
        // encode the bitstream
        return processData(rawData, len/2);
    }

    /**
     * Encode an array of shorts.
     * @param data
     * @param offset
     * @param numShorts
     * @return true if successful.
     */
    public boolean processData(final short[] data,
            final int offset,
            final int numShorts)
    {
        int numSamplesRequired = channels * frameSize;
        if (numShorts != numSamplesRequired) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("SpeexEncoder requires " + numSamplesRequired + " samples to process a Frame, not " + numShorts);
        }
        // convert shorts into float samples,
        for (int i=0; i<numShorts; i++) {
            rawData[i] = data[offset + i ];
        }
        // encode the bitstream
        return processData(rawData, numShorts);
    }

    /**
     * Encode an array of floats.
     * @param data
     * @param numSamples
     * @return true if successful.
     */
    public boolean processData(final float[] data, final int numSamples)
    {
        int numSamplesRequired = channels * frameSize;
        if (numSamples != numSamplesRequired) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("SpeexEncoder requires " + numSamplesRequired + " samples to process a Frame, not " + numSamples );
        }
        // encode the bitstream
        if (channels==2) {
            Stereo.encode(bits, data, frameSize);
        }
        encoder.encode(bits, data);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a 16 bit linear PCM stream (in the form of a byte array)
     * into a floating point PCM stream (in the form of an float array).
     * Here are some important details about the encoding:
     * <ul>
     * <li> Java uses big endian for shorts and ints, and Windows uses little Endian.
     *      Therefore, shorts and ints must be read as sequences of bytes and
     *      combined with shifting operations.
     * </ul>
     * @param pcm16bitBytes - byte array of linear 16-bit PCM formated audio.
     * @param offsetInput
     * @param samples - float array to receive the 16-bit linear audio samples.
     * @param offsetOutput
     * @param length
     */
    public static void mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float(final byte[] pcm16bitBytes,
            final int offsetInput,
            final float[] samples,
            final int offsetOutput,
            final int length)
    {
        if (pcm16bitBytes.length - offsetInput < 2 * length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient Samples to convert to floats");
        }
        if (samples.length - offsetOutput < length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient float buffer to convert the samples");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            samples[offsetOutput+i] = ((pcm16bitBytes[offsetInput+2*i] & 0xff) | (pcm16bitBytes[offsetInput+2*i+1] << 8)); // no & 0xff at the end to keep the sign
        }
    }

    // public int getProcessedData(byte[] temp, int i) {
    //  return 0;
    //      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    //  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this but this is giving a lot of errors